# Xcode Build Errors After Pod Update

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, mbprogresshud, svprogresshud

I just did a pod update and tried to build my project; getting the following errors: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'changelater' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks


use_frameworks!

  # Pods for changelater
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Functions'
    pod 'ProgressHUD'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'Stripe', '15.0.1'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlacesSearchController'
    pod 'GooglePlacePicker'

end
```

Any idea why I am getting this error after update? and how I can fix it?  I already did `shift+command+K` but it's not helping.

Comment: Your have `platform :ios, '10.0'` in your podfile, but your apps seems to be configured for deployment to iOS 13 - could that be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just because I didnt have the latest xcode. So I had to update my xcode and update my podfile versions. Everything was fine after that!

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning your project is a good practice after updating your pod dependencies.
I had similar issues in the past after updating cocoapods.

Try

1. In Xcode menu: Product -> Clean build folder (shift+command+K)
2. Build your project again (command+B)

Comment: I have don that too but it still gives me the same errors

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to update my xcode to the latest version and the errors disappeared.